How can I create a VM in virt-manager that can access the internet through the host but can't even see the host or other devices on the LAN?
I want to be able to create multiple VMs for testing purposes -- questionable websites, files that could be infected with a virus, etc.
I want to make sure these VMs should be able to access the internet but they should not be able to access the host or any other device on the LAN.
I tried NAT mode but that let's me access the host and other devices on the LAN.
I tried Isolated mode but that doesn't give me internet access.
I don't want to run a second VM and route traffic through it.
I want to avoid creating FW rules on the host or VMs because I'll be creating and destroying VMs all the time.
What do I need to do?
